# Ant build script to run a batch file, while passing user input to batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, ant, cmd, build.xml

I am writing a build script that is meant to execute a .bat file, with the user providing input before pressing enter to execute the ant script.  I have used the bat file already, and it works well, but I have never tried integrating a bat file into a build script before, especially one that requires input.  The build script without the input component should look like this I believe:

```
<target name="css-val">
    <exec dir="M:\burnjc_view\ServiceTeams\Team 4\Report\CssValidation\bin" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
        <arg line="/c cssvalFile.bat"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The bat file that requires input to run properly looks like this:

```
java -jar css-validator.jar -output gnu file:///%1 > ..\output\%2
```

Input 1 is the file and directory of a file to be validated by css-validator.jar, while 2 is the filename of the output.

How do I get the ant script to pass input to the bat file it is executing so that it works almost like someone was executing the bat file by itself?  I know the first part of the user input to run the whole thing will be "ant css-val", but afterward I do not know how to pass input to the bat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters using `-D` switch:

```
-D<property>=<value>    Defines a property name-value pair on the command line.
```

and you can refer to this parameter with `${<property>}`

For example:

```
<target name="css-val">
    <exec dir="M:\burnjc_view\ServiceTeams\Team 4\Report\CssValidation\bin" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
        <arg line="/c cssvalFile.bat ${file1} ${file2}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

and while running

```
ant -Dfile1=somefile -Dfile2=somefile build.xml
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it does, but after looking further into the command line arguments, I am beginning to think it may be best to create input prompts in the ant task and then pass inputs to the bat file.  The fact that you have the inputs on the arg line though helped the most.

Answer (score 2):

Although Sanjeev's answer is what got me here due to how he showed that input went on the same line as the arg line, I thought it would be instructive to also include an alternative answer where the user is prompted for inputs (this also allows for input validation, a feature I will show later).  As I refine my build script, I may update this code as well to show other useful features:

```
<target name="css-val">
    <input
        message="Please enter directory and filename of file to be validated:  "
        addproperty="validate.file"
    />
    <input
        message="Enter directory and file name to use for output report:  "
        addproperty="report.file"
    />
    <exec dir=""M:\burnjc_view\ServiceTeams\Team 4\Report\CssValidation\bin" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
        <arg line="/c cssValSoapFile.bat ${validate.file} ${report.file}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The above will not work if there are any spaces in one of the arguments, as each argument is separated by space.  In that situation, use arg value instead of arg line.  More to write, but it works when there are spaces.