# Ant exec, How to arg

Tags: ant

So I have the below build file:

```
<target name="test">
    <echo message="test"></echo>
    <exec executable="C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\cmd.bat" >
        <arg value="exit"/>
        <arg value="mkdir C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\ant\test"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I thought it would create a test folder there but its not. It pops out another command prompt window, I thought the exit would close that but it doesn't. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

---

The content of bath script test1.bat:

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

And ant's build.xml:

```
<target name="test">
    <echo message="test"></echo>
    <exec executable="C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\ant\test1.cmd">
        <arg value="hello"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: what is the content of "cmd.bat" ? (not really a good name for script".. this clashes with windows' own cmd...    related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042203/ant-build-script-to-run-a-batch-file-while-passing-user-input-to-batch-file

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand how the executable and the arg value was working. Your question is correct. I got an example for this below.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official documentation:

> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the
>   /c switch

Follow this format instead:

```
<target name="help">
  <exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="ant.bat"/>
    <arg value="-p"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Source: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html